# How to install the Bolt beta with CLI

Tags: bolt-cms

Well, the title says it, it's a SSH question actually: how can I install a Bolt Beta from the CLI?

My guess would be - for the current latest Beta:

```
curl -O https://github.com/bolt/bolt/archive/v2.0.0-beta4pl3.zip
unzip v2.0.0-beta4pl3.zip
chmod -R 777 files/ app/database/ app/cache/ app/config/ theme/
```

but I want to be sure that I don't screw things up. No flag needed in the second line?

Comment: (if this is possible at all...)

Answer (score 1):

The docs for version 2 use the latest tarball (the one with the underscore goes to bolt 1.6)
You can see other files at https://bolt.cm/distribution/

```
curl -O https://bolt.cm/distribution/bolt-2.0.0-beta5.tar.gz
tar -xzf bolt-2.0.0-beta5.tar.gz --strip-components=1
chmod -R 777 files/ app/database/ app/cache/ app/config/ theme/ extensions/
```

For the updated docs you can view the work in progress at https://docs.bolt.cm/installation